# Intellij SSH to remote DB

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how I can connect to my DB via SSH using the IntelliJ "Database" feature. We are using OpenShift and there is one pod running, which is only our connection to our DB.

Example:

`oc rsh pod_name`

After that comes the psql connection string to login into our DB.

Can I somehow point to my script, so I can connect or is there a better way? The issue with this is, the pod name is dynamically changed now and then. That's why I want to point to my script which solves this issue by fuzzy searching the pod name.

Answer (score 0):

[here is doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-ssh-and-ssl.html) on how to connect using SSH. How does your script work? can you point it to change pod name in OpenSSH config for example and do not establish SSH connection? Then you just use this config in Intellij with alias to create ssh tunnel and use it with database connection.

or there is another way: in data source properties on 'Options' tab you can use 'Before connection' configuration where you can add your script, which will create ssh tunnel using some static local port and set in database connection 'localhost:port'.